# How to allow outbound traffic on internal load balancer

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-load-balancer

I have several machines in a backend pool associated with an internal load balancer. However, they currently do not have outbound access.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/egress-only) seems to indicate that I should be able to create a public load balancer and attach the same backend pool with it so that I can have outbound access from those machines.  However, when I create a public load balancer, I don't have the option of associating it with an existing pool, and when I try to create a new backend pool for the public LB I can't associate those machines with it.  Neither machine has a public IP address.  From the dashboard it shows:

[image: azure portal error message]

where all the interesting info is cut off.   What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using Standard SKU Load Balancer and IPs?

Comment: Yes, standard SKU load balancer for the internal LB.  For the external one I have tried w/ both standard and basic models, with standard IP. No public IPs on the VMs.  They are not meant to be accessible from the outside - however, they do query outside sources.

Answer (score 0):

Even VM's in the backend pool of an ILB should have a default outbound IP. If you don't have outbound access have you checked the security group rules to make sure outbound traffic is allowed?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do this on the same LB for both inbound & outbound traffic.

1. If you happen to use the `Basic` SKU, VMs behind the LB have internet
   access as outbound connections are NAT'ed by Azure. But, all VMs have to be in the same AZ. This wasn't a great idea & we declined it
2. If you use a `Standard` SKU, outbound connections to the internet are not possible. We learned this after many failed & painful attempts. More details [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c324d260-d0a6-4c0d-ad66-82e52df0b715/unable-to-access-to-internet-with-a-standard-load-balancer?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows)
3. As discussed in the above link, attaching a public IP to each VM nic isn't a good idea either
4. What worked for us is to create another LoadBalancer specifically for outbound connections, attach public IP to that LB & configure outbound rules. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/outbound-rules)

Comment: Thanks - sorry if my original post wasn't clear.  I already have a standard SKU internal LB, and am trying to also add a second public LB, not use the same one for both inbound and outbound.  My understanding is that I should be able to attach the same backend pool (or 2 pools with same VMs) to both, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: I get your question, but that's not possible unfortunately. Otherwise, why we would be using another LB? Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/egress-only) for more details.

Comment: Sorry, I did read again. So, outbound via another LB egress is not working? This is weird.. We have many such setups & it always worked. Looks like something is wrong at your end.

Comment: It just wasn't letting me create another backend pool that contained the VMs of interest, or to assign the same VM backend pool to the new egress LB.  Per OP, the error message not particularly helpful...  Good to know that it works for you all.  Are both standard SKU?